# Does testcafe support to load any crx extensions and also setup ModHeader extension with the custom header values in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Does testcafe support to load crx extensions in Chrome browser?

If so, please let me know what method needs to try out.

I tried below the code it doesn’t work out

```
await t.eval(new Function(fs.readFileSync('/foo.crx').toString()));
```

And also testcafe support to setup ModHeader extension with the custom header values.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome extension file is an archive, which can contain not only `.js` files, but also `.html`, `.css` and any other file types. This means that it is not possible to install an extension via the `t.eval` function which executes JavaScript code.

If you only need to execute some `js` code from the extension, you can extract your `crx` file using the https://crxextractor.com/ service and call the `eval` function for the unpacked `.js` file.

As I understand, you want to use the `ModHeader` extension for intercepting HTTP requests, modify header values and so on. If so, please take a look at the built-in [Request Hooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/) functionality which allows you to accomplish this task.

Comment: Thanks much Alex Skorkin , can you please let me know which testcafe version support on above request and also does testcafe suport to do resource override ( i have base url like www.abc.com/ . , i waned to override one of bundle build(from https://prod.bundle.build.js to https://test.bundle.build.js) , if so t.eval function which executes JavaScript code will work ? please help me on this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'above request'. There's no TestCafe version that supports the Chrome extension load. You can use the navigateTo action to switch your target web page. You might want to ask separate questions on StackOverflow regarding your further inquiries.